# Dropbox api for Delphi?

Tags: delphi, dropbox

I am considering using DropBox to sync user data with a delphi app.  It would seem to solve lots of problems regarding security, permissions, etc... I see that there are some API samples for C#, python, etc..  Has anyone done it with Delphi, and if so, are there samples available?

Comment: Sorry, no updates!  I've been distracted by other things and this project got sidetracked. I'm still interested though, and hope to get back to it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [DropBox API](https://www.dropbox.com/developers) is a generic web based API, either using [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Json) over HTTP or [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer) (also over HTTP) calling into the DropBox web server using an API key.

All [language specific wrappers](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/releases) are just bindings around this API:
they either encapsulate the JSON over HTTP or REST over HTTP calls.

For a Delphi implementation, rolling your own JSON wrapper is probably the easiest.

There are various ways of doing JSON in Delphi.
Starting with Delphi 2010 on, it contains a [native JSON implementation](http://blogs.embarcadero.com/adrian/2009/08/19/json-types-for-server-methods-in-datasnap-2010/).
Up until Delphi 2009, you can use [SuperObject](http://www.progdigy.com/?page_id=6) for JSON.
This [post from Daniele Teti and the comment thread Below it](http://www.danieleteti.it/?p=189) explain them both.

--jeroen

Comment: Thanks - I had read right past the JSON/REST stuff and was thinking that I had to talk to a DLL.  Thanks for the links!  If I cook up a working example, I'll post it back here.

Comment: @Chris: you are welcome; I'm looking forward to your sample!